# How to write the let implementation in Scheme using define-syntax

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I think I have the general idea here conceptually, but the syntax is obivously wrong

```
(define-syntax mylet
  (syntax-rules ( )
    ((mylet definitions evaluation)
     ((lambda (map car definitions) evaluations) (map cdar definitions)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much more intuitive than Common Lisp. Really. We can just use ellipses for that.

```
(define-syntax mylet
  (syntax-rules ( )
    ((mylet ((name val) ...) body ...)
     ((lambda (name ...) body ...) val ...))))
```